# How to read recursive List in java

Tags: java, android, list, class, recursion

I can not read a recursive list of items.

I have a tree of categories, each category has children, which in turn can have children (do not know how many).

This is my class:

```
public class Category {
    public int HasChild = 0;
    public int level;
    public boolean isOpened = false;
    @ElementList(entry = "Category", required = false, empty = true, data = true, inline = true)
    private List<Category> childrenCategory;

    @Attribute(required = false)
    private String id;
    @ElementList(entry = "Name", inline = true, required = false)
    public List<Name> name;

    public List<Category> getCategoy() {
        return childrenCategory;
    }

    public void setCategoy(List<Category> categoy) {
        childrenCategory = categoy;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<Name> getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(List<Name> name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Category [childrenCategory=" + childrenCategory + ", id=" + id
                + "]";
    }

}
```

This is my function where a foreach control Things will:

```
    void function(Category cat) {
        for (Category iterable_element : cat.getCategoy()) {
            Log.i("link", iterable_element.toString());
            if (cat.getCategoy() != null) {
                //
//              holder.btn.setEnabled(true);
//              cat.HasChild = 1;
                Log.i("link", "isEmpity");

            }
        }
```

Here is where you call the function, where the oject initial step:

```
object = category;
            function(object);
```

my problem is that I can control in this way Things will only top level if I would like to access those second level should do:

object = category.getCategoy().get(0);
        function(object);

but this is not possible because everything has to be recursive, and not hand written.

Should I once read the first iterate the oject to the next level

help me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Call the function recursively. Here is the code.

```
void function(Category cat) {
    if (cat.getCategoy().size() > 0) {
        for (Category iterable_element : cat.getCategoy()) {
            log.i("Has "+cat.getCategoy().size() + "  children.");
            function(iterable_element);  // again call it recursively
        }
    } 
    else {
        log.i("No children.");
    }
}
```